# Consider the Fibonacci sequence, give a proof by induction to show that 3 | f4n, for all n ≥ 1

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have to show by mathematical induction that 3 | f4n, for all n ≥ 1

Base Case : f4(1) = f4 = 3 which is divisible by 3.

Inductive Hypothesis (IH): Assume 3 | f4k for all k ≥ 1

Inductive step (IS): Show 3 | f4(k+1)

In order to show that 3 | f4(k+1), I said that 3 will always be divisible by f4k as long as k≥1 as we showed in the IH. Hence, (k+1) can be any integer as long as k≥1 and it's a multiple of 4. So, 3 | f4(k+1) will always be true. I don't know how to show this mathematically tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five consecutive Fibonacci numbers are of the form $a,\,b,\,a+b,\,a+2b,\,2a+3b$. If $3|a$ then $3|2a+3b$.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to prove is that $f_{4(n + 1)}$ is divisible by 3 (or that it has a factor of 3 in it) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. You have to prove that the proposition holds for your base case: $f_4$ which it surely does.
Now you assume $f_{4n}$ holds and prove that $f_{4(n + 1)}$ also holds.

To do this, define $f_{4n} = 3m, \hspace{2mm} m \in \mathbb{N}$, (definition of multiple of 3).

Now, we have to construct $f_{4(n + 1)}$, Fibonacci numbers are defined by their predecesors in the form:

$$ f_n = f_{n - 1} + f_{n - 2}$$

We also define $f_{4n - 1} = k, \hspace{2mm} k \in \mathbb{N}$ (this just tells us that it is a natural number, as $F \subset \mathbb{N}$).

We can now procede to construct $f_{4(n + 1)}$ as follows:

$$ f_{4n + 1} = f_{4n} + f_{4n - 1} = 3m + k $$

$$ f_{4n + 2} = f_{4n + 1} + f_{4n} = (3m + k) + (3m) = (6m + k)$$

$$ f_{4n + 3} = f_{4n + 2} + f_{4n + 1} = (6m + k) + (3m + k) = (9m + 2k)$$

$$ f_{4n + 4} = f_{4n + 3} + f_{4n + 2} = (9m + 2k) + (6m + k) = (15m + 3k)$$

Now, we can factor out 3 in the last step:

$$ f_{4n + 4} = 3(5m + k)$$

but $ f_{4n + 4} = f_{4(n + 1)} $, we showed that if the proposition for $f_{4n}$ holds, it also holds for $ f_{4(n + 1)}$